# get_comments not working on custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I am trying to get all the comments of the logged in user in the "foods" CPT but I'm still with no success.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'user_id' => $user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'foods', // when I removed this, the list only showed the comments left on posts but not on Foods CPT
        );

    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if ( $comments )
    {
        $output.= '<ul>';
        foreach ( $comments as $c )
        {
        $output.= '<li>';
        $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
        $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
        $output.= '</a>, Posted on: '. mysql2date('m/d/Y', $c->comment_date, $translate);
        $output.= "</li>\n";
        }
        $output.= '</ul>';



        echo $output;


    } else { echo "<p>No comments yet.</p>";}
?>
```

This code returns no comments despite me, the user, commenting on posts in Foods CPT. Plus, when I deleted the post_type line, instead of showing all the comments I made, it only showed the comments I left on Posts and not on Foods CPT.

I created the CPT through WP Types but to ensure that it's not the plugin that's making the problem, I manually created another CPT in the functions file and commented on the post I created there. Still, my comment in this CPT did not show.

What could be the problem behind this?

Comment: How you created the Foods CPT? Can you share the CPT code?

Comment: I created it using the WP Types plugin.

Comment: are you added 'comments' in support section? Are you getting the discussion section below the WP Editor at dashboard?

Comment: Yes, it appears in the Comments section of the Dashboard.

Comment: Because the post has no comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, **'user_id' => $user->ID,** is not working since I did not set global current_user on. The first three lines should be replaced with something like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
```

Now it's working :)